# Solve equations and express with specific varible

Tags: equation-solving

I have two equations as below:

eq1: $8 \pi  \gamma  r-\frac{4 \pi  \text{Delta$\_\mu $} r^2}{\text{v$\_$c}}=0$

eq2: $\text{Delta$\_\mu $}=\text{K$\_$b} S T$

When I try `Solve[{eq1}, {r}]`, I obtained $\left\{\{r\to 0\},\left\{r\to \frac{2 \gamma  \text{v$\_$c}}{\text{Delta$\_\mu $}}\right\}\right\}$.

This is correct, but I want it is expressed as $\left\{r\to \frac{2 \gamma  \text{v$\_$c}}{\text{K$\_$b} S T}\right\}$. I tried `Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {r}]` but I obtained `{}`

How can I get the result expressed with K_b, S and T instead of Delta_u? Many thanks!

Comment: it is better to post the actual Mathematica plain source code you used. Also `_` can't be used in variable names.

Comment: Try [Eliminate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html).

Comment: Or `Solve` for both `Delta_u` and `r` (I trust the actual "variable" does not have an underbar in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Format[v[c]] := Subscript[v, c];
Format[K[b]] := Subscript[K, b];
Format[Delta[u]] := Subscript[Delta, u];

Solve[8 π γ r - 4 π Delta[u] r^2/v[c] == 0, r] /. 
 Delta[u] -> K[b] S T
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want. Sorry that I cannot vote for your answer since I do not have sufficient reputation.